# Tension at lowest point: oberbeck pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I'm solving a problem involving oberbeck pendulum

[image]

> We are given $M$, $m$, $r$ (radius of pulley), $R$ (distance from center of rotation to each of the 4 small weights). The problem says that the weight descends from a height $h$, reaches the lowest point and then begins to rise.
>
> We are asked to find the tension $T$ during the time that the weight is changing directions.

This are the equations of motion for the system:
$$I=4mR^2$$
$$I\frac{dw}{dt}=Tr$$
$$Ma=Mg-T$$
$$\frac{dw}{dt}=\frac{a}{r}$$

I managed to find acceleration $a_0$ and tension $T_0$ during the time that the weight is descending/ascending, but I I'm stuck at finding the tension during the time that it is changing directions.
$$a_0=\frac{Mg}{\frac{I}{r^2}+M}$$
$$T_0=\frac{Mg}{1+\frac{r^2M}{I}}$$

I found a solution that says this: during the time of the "yank", the pulley makes a $180^\circ$ turn, not changing its angular velocity (given the high moment of intertia). So we get:
$$(T-Mg)\Delta t=2Mv$$
$\Delta t = \frac{\pi r}{v}$, and $v$ is the velocity when it reaches the lowest point.

As I understand, the pendulum keeps rotating, since the torque created by this change in tension $\Delta T$ is small, taking into account the moment of intertia of the system. But why is it that the tension $T=T_0+\Delta T$ acts only during this $180^\circ$ rotationi and then it goes back to being $T_0$? It kind of makes sense at an intuitive level, but I don't know what physics law backs it up.

It's my first time posting here, thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Although a very late comment, at the turning point the rope's tension gives the mass at the bottom an *impulse* in order to change the direction of its velocity, and impulse results in force.